# Unable to login to docker registry using podman on macOS - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: macos, x509certificate, docker-registry, podman

I am trying to use podman (version: 3.2.3) to login to a private docker registry.

I am using the default VM installed when doing `podman machine init`

The certificate (i.e. `.pem` file) is installed in macOS’s keychain.

When I run:

```
podman login myhost.io
```

After entering my username and password, I get:

```
Error: authenticating creds for "myhost.io": error pinging docker registry myhost.io: Get "https://myhost.io/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Can I use the certificate saved in keychain? Or can I use the .pem file with `—-authfile`?

Thanks for help and suggestions.

Comment: I created this related issue on GitHub too: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11507

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe podman can read macos keychain properly (yet).

As a workaround, try not verifying the certificate.

```
podman login --tls-verify=false myhost.io
```

Comment: `--tls-verify=false` allows a user to skip a `self-signed` certificate but does not allow one to ignore a certificate sighed by a *Certificate Authority*. See link to `man` page / documentation in subsequent answer.

Comment: It worked for my "certificate signed by unknown authority" error

Answer (score 0):

You do not state what registry you have deployed, but depending on how you've set it up or if you picked something like `harbor` then the option you are probably looking for is `--cert=path` as described in the [podman login](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-login.1.html) documentation.  The certificate you are looking for is the *Certificate Authority* for the registry; in the case of `harbor` can be downloaded from the web interface.

The documentation also states a user friendly location to store such certificates under the following path:

```
# Default path
/etc/containers/certs.d

# Example
/etc/containers/certs.d/myhost.io
```

Alternatively, use the option: `--cert`.

Please note that the option `--tls-verify=false` option is used typically for self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 0):

put your self signed certificate to

```sh
/etc/containers/certs.d/
```

and use `podman login` command with  tag `--tls-verify`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when deploying a private registry in rhel8; the reason for this is the self-signed cert;
You have to copy the cert from server to the client:
step1. scp server:/opt/registry/cert/xxx.crt client:/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
step2.  update-ca-trust

Answer (score -4):

`/etc/docker/daemon.json` Add

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myhost.io"]
}
```

Restart docker instance.

[References](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, but your suggestion is specific to Docker and Linux. My issue is using podman on macOS. Also accessing our registry insecurely is not an option for my use case.

Comment: @softinio which is why this question shouldn't have been tagged with `docker`.